# Why does this code work?

Tags: javascript

I thought if statements weren't supposed to contain assignment operators but rather the comparison operators (==, ===) but this works perfectly. Why?

```
var foo = true,
    bar = true;
if (foo = true) {
    console.log('foo is true');
}
```

I was taught that this wouldn't work but I just found out that it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ES5.1 specification (12.5)

```
IfStatement :
    if ( Expression ) Statement  else Statement
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

Any valid expression can be placed inside an if.

`foo = true` is an expression and it evaluates to true.

To avoid bugs like writing `=` instead of `==` in the future write it like

```
if (true = foo) {

}
```

Which will throw a assignment error since you can't assign values to literal values like `true`

Comment: +1 for *embracing* errors and using them to your advantage instead of trying to hide them in the closet as is sometimes recommended.

Comment: @patrick_dw why did you stop lurking on chat.SO :( Who else am I supposed to ask the _Really_ hard questions to.

Comment: Raynos: You ask awesome questions. I've learned as much from your questions as from your excellent answers. Not much time to chat, but I'll stop by and say hi sometime.

Answer (score 6):

What you're actually doing, is still comparing:

```
if ((foo = true) == true) ...
```

This is an 'abbreviation' for:

```
foo = true;
if (foo == true) ...
```

So it does make sense =)!

Comment: @Andrew, being `foo = 'Hello World`;' and comparing it against `true` will yield `false` (when the type of one of the operands is boolean, both are converted to Number, e.g.: `'1' == true`), I think you meant `if (foo)`. Also agree, jslint isn't law, it's just the personal view (some times quite authoritative) of an individual about the language. :)

Answer (score 3):

The assignment is evaluated to `true`, beacuse JavaScript returns the value that it sets the variable to.

```
var foo = true,
    bar = true;
if (foo = true) {
    console.log('foo is true');
}
```

becomes:

```
var foo = true,
    bar = true;
if (true) {
    console.log('foo is true');
}
```

which passes the `if`. Note that setting to `false` would not work, because the conditional would evaluate to `false` which does not pass the `if`.

Specification about `if`:

> if ( Expression ) Statement

You are using the assignment expression:

> AssignmentExpression :
>   ConditionalExpression LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

The `=` is specified as:

> Simple Assignment ( = )
>
> The production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 2 . Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
>
> 3 . Let rval be GetValue(rref).
>
> ...
>
> **6. Return rval.**

Answer (score 1):

Tragically, you are in fact assigning foo to true. :)